# Adding a global resource folder to gradle build to be made available for subprojects

Tags: scala, gradle, resources, classpath

I have a gradle project which consists of a number of subprojects. I want to add a resource folder which is in the same folder as the subprojects to be on the classpath of all the projects when they run.

The folder structure kinda looks like:

```
root
|__subproject1
|__subproject2
|__subproject3
|__global_resources
```

I've tried doing something like in the root `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    processResources {
        from("$rootProject/global_resources/")
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        runtime fileTree(dir: "$rootProject/resources", includes: '*.txt')
    }
}
```

But running any of the subprojects gives an error that the resource it needs is not available.

How do I go about doing this?

Not sure if it's useful, but this is a scala project. I'm not accustomed to writing gradle tasks, so please don't answer with "make a gradle task to do that". I'm sure it's probably that simple, but I don't have any examples to go with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest and most re-usability friendly way would be to do place all your "global" resources in "global_resources/src/main/resources", add build.gradle to your global_resources folder:

```
root
|__..projects..
|__global_resources
|____src
|______main
|_________resources
|___________ ...your resource files...
|____build.gradle
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"

name="global_resources"
```

And then include this project in your other projects:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":global_resources")
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but I still get the same results. The project is built and I see that the resource files are placed in the build directory, but running any of the other projects it seems, the file is not found

Comment: Is there a way to also include the global_resource resource path in the path of the other subprojects?

Comment: @smac89 if they're in the build folder.... perhaps you're not accessing them correctly?

Comment: Yup! I just realised that. I was using Scala's `Source.fromFile` method rather than `Source.fromInputStream`...Now it's working!