# How to add resource folder in gradle and other resource folder

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project whose structure is in below manner

```
src----
       |
       pdstat---------------------------------------
       resources/test.properties                     |
                                                     |
                                                     a
                                                     b
                                                     c
                                                     d
                                                     resource[having xsd file]
```

I need to create the jar file which will include everything.My problem is after making jar file it doesn't include the resource folder

```
project.jar
|
-----------------psdstat
|
------------------test.properties[without resources folder]
```

and it is also not including the resources[xsd file] folder which is inside the medstat. This is ant project and I am converting it into gradle.I can't change the structure of the project

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: `src/main/resources`.. All subfolders should go in there

Comment: Your diagram is not clear. Are `a, b, c, d, resource[having xsd file]` all folders nested under pdstat?

Comment: Yes it is under pdstat and only resource folder is having xsd file.Rest are having java files

Comment: @cricket_007 changing the structure will break lots of things

Comment: Well, if you follow the Gradle Java plugin documentation, that is the format  you must follow

Comment: I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194562/adding-a-global-resource-folder-to-gradle-build-to-be-made-available-for-subproj). See if that helps. The basic idea is to create another subproject in the format mentioned by @cricket_007, then make your project depend on this subproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in below way and it is working fine

```
task copynonJavafile<< {
copy{
 from("src"){
  exclude '**/*.java' }
 into("build/classes/main")
}
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir  'test'

        }
    }
}

jar.dependsOn copynonJavafile
```